# How to extend angular @input decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-decorator

I'm trying to write custom property decorator for extending skills of angular @Input decorator.

My goal is to get Localizable property with existing property selector.

**./decorators/my-decorators.ts**

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';
export interface InputDefinition {localizable: boolean; selector: string; }
export function MyInput(inputDefinition: InputDefinition) {
    const ngInput = Input(inputDefinition.selector);
    return function (target: any, key: string) {
        if (inputDefinition.localizable === true) {
            console.log(`loclizable input ${inputDefinition.selector}`);
            // implement localization for property.
        }
      ngInput(target, key);
    };
}
```

**./my-component/mycomponent.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MyInput } from '../decorators/my-decorators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<h1>{{myInput}}</h1>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  //define input property with custom decorator 
  @MyInput({selector: 'my-input', localizable: false})
  myInput = 'input default value';
}
```

**./app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <my-component my-input="bound value"></my-component>
</div>
```

`ng serve`
[image]

seems to work great but when I run it in prod mode..

`--ng serve --prod`
[image]

has no any build error or runtime error but property binding not working in prod build.

All kinds of suggestions will help.

thanks in advance

```
ng -version


Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, elements
... forms, http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.4
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.4
@angular/cli                      6.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.4
@schematics/angular               0.8.4
@schematics/update                0.8.4
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.20.2
```

Comment: Why not create a separate decorator (`@Localizable()`)? I think AOT does some optimizations with the Input decorator at compile time...

Comment: it won't work with aot. https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#annotationsdecorators

Comment: @AndreiTătar What if you need to access the property binding name in your decorator, how would you do that with a separate one?

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?
I'm trying to do the same thing and I get the error `Can't bind to '<property with custom decorated>' since it isn't a known property of '<component selector>'.